# How do I pass a parameter file to quartz component?

Tags: apache-camel

Read documentation https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quartz-component.html

propertiesFile (consumer)    File name of the properties to load from the classpath

My route

```
from("quartz://test/receive?cron=0+0+*+*+*+?&propertiesFile=quartz.properties")
.to("mock:done");
```

Return error:
Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{propertiesFile=quartz.properties}]}]

Repeats at Apache Camel 3.0, 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring quartz endpoint. "propertiesFile" is field of quartz component.
Make something like that:

```
 QuartzComponent component = new QuartzComponent(getContext());
    component.setPropertiesFile("quartz.properties");
    getContext().getRegistry().bind("quartz", component);
```